# Triggering TeamCity job based on email subject

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I'm newly implementing TeamCity and earlier was using Jenkins to implement CI. So I'm looking to know if there is any option (preferably inbuilt) to trigger TeamCity jobs by polling my mailbox and trigger when there is some mail with subject `::Ready to START::`.

In Jenkins we have some plugin to poll our mail box and trigger the build, couldn't find similar option in TeamCity. Please help.

Comment: the bad way to trigger the CI

Comment: well not really... it depends upon the situation/requirement...

Comment: Darn, I was hoping for this to be integrated too. I suppose you write a few lines of code, e.g. create a Cloudflare Worker to receive email https://developers.cloudflare.com/email-routing/email-workers/, then when you get an email, just hit the TeamCity REST API with an API token you've stored as a secret in Cloudflare. Probably would just be a few lines.